# Delphi 10.3.3 Rio - Dock Form loses Tmenu items

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm doing the classic Dock a form on a PageControl in my Main Form. This works well, except for the TMenu for every form that I dock does not show on the PageControl -> newly created TabSheet. I'm currently using Delphi 10.3.3 Rio. Any suggestions?
[image]

```
    {Start}
    {CreateForm}
    Application.CreateForm(TFormSQLExecute, FormSQLExecute);
    {Form Attributes}
    FormSQLExecute.AutoScroll:=true;
    FormSQLExecute.AutoSize:=true;
    {Dock Settings}
    FormSQLExecute.Position:=poDefaultPosOnly;
    FormSQLExecute.DragKind:=dkDock;
    FormSQLExecute.DragMode:=dmAutomatic;
    FormSQLExecute.WindowState:=wsMaximized;
    FormSQLExecute.ManualDock(FormMain.PageControlDock);
    {Show}
    result:=false;
    FormSQLExecute.Show;
   {Finish}
```

Here is a screen shot below with a working TMenu. The only difference instead of Show I use ShowModal for this example.
[image]

Comment: Menus are restricted to top level windows. A docked form is a child window.

Comment: You might want to look at action menus.